# What is the acceleration of a two weights connected with wire?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acceleration

Given 2 weights:

**m1 = 2 kg**

**m2 = 1 kg**

They are connected with wire hung over stick and considering there are no wire friction.
Find the acceleration of weight **m1** going down. Find the (force) tension of the wire.

---

My try:

```
    F1 - F2 = ma

    m1g-m2g=ma

    9.8*(2-1)=ma

    a=9.8/2
```

$$ a=4.9\; \text{m}/\text{s}^2 $$ 
Correct answer: $$ a=3.27\; \text{m}/\text{s}^2 $$ and **F = 13.1 H**

---

What's wrong? How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $m$ should be $m1+m2$.......

Comment: What about F? F=ma => F=(2+1)*3.27 = 9.81 ...

Comment: The force in the wire has to support $m2$ against gravity and pull enough to accelerate it by this amount, so$ F=m2(\frac 43g)$

Comment: where came $\frac{4}{3}$ from?

Comment: Beacuse it is accelerating at $\frac 13g$

Answer (score 0):

Considering forces on each mass separately : 
$$F_1-T=m_1a$$
$$T-F_2=m_2a$$

adding these 2 equations :

$$F_1-F_2=(m_1+m_2)a$$
$$\Rightarrow a=\frac{(m_1-m_2)g}{m_1+m_2}$$

$$\Rightarrow >a=9.8/3=3.27$$